# Find the duplicates in the Xml column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlxml

I have a table with the following sample columns with data as given below. Each account number has a corresponding `createddt` and `xmlpayload` column values.

In the given 4 rows, I need to find the valid duplicates. Each valid account number has 2 xml rows (one statement and one pdf xml record). If the account number has 2 records with same type of xml root node like pdf record (2335577) it should be a duplicate. How to filter the exact duplicates by querying the xml column. Please help.

```
Records:  
    AccountNo   **Xmlpayload**  
    2335566     <ns0:Statement xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/><ns0:Statement>
    2335566     <ns0:PDFStmt xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:PDFStmt> 
    2335577     <ns0:PDFStmt xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:PDFStmt>       
    2335577     <ns0:PDFStmt xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:PDFStmt>      
    4332355     <ns0:PDFStmt xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:PDFStmt>       
    4332355     <ns0:Statement xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:Statement>      
    6723588     <ns0:Statement xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:Statement>       
    6723588     <ns0:Statement xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:Statement>   

My Expected Output:  
    2335577     <ns0:PDFStmt xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:PDFStmt>       
    2335577     <ns0:PDFStmt xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:PDFStmt>      
    6723588     <ns0:Statement xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:Statement>       
    6723588     <ns0:Statement xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123<empid/></ns0:Statement>
```

I am using SQL 2008 R2 version.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server you can use [exist()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method from sqlxml, like this:

```
with xmlnamespaces ('uri' as ns0)
select *
from Table1 as t
where t.Xmlpayload.exist('ns0:PDF[2]') = 1
```

or you can use xquery [count()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189963.aspx) function with [value()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method:

```
with xmlnamespaces ('uri' as ns0)
select *
from Table1 as t
where t.Xmlpayload.value('count(ns0:PDF)', 'int') > 1;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eef02/11)</kbd>**

**update**

If you have one for each AccountNo, you can use this query:

```
with xmlnamespaces ('uri' as ns0)
select *
from Table2 as t
where t.Xmlpayload.exist('ns0:PDFStmt[2]') = 1
```

If you have several rows for each AccountNo (and want to get Xmlpayload in the resultset):

```
with
xmlnamespaces ('uri' as ns0),
cte as (
    select
        *, count(*) over(partition by AccountNo) as cnt
    from Table1 as t
    where t.Xmlpayload.exist('ns0:PDFStmt') = 1
)
select *
from cte
where cnt > 1;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2425b/8)</kbd>**

Comment: Hey Roman, I have just restructured my records and given you the expected output. I ran your query and it's not fetching me any resultset. I need the duplicate for each account number filtering based on the root node name. Please see the expected output.

Comment: @user1762476 do you have 4 rows and xml having two elements or do you have 8 rows?

Comment: Your query got me the duplicates.Thanks!! I resolved myself using the below query which i applied for both pdfstmt and statement root node. WITH Xmlnamespaces ('uri' AS ns0) SELECT C1.query('fn:local-name(.)') AS Nodes, xmlPayload.value('(/ns0:PDFStmt/AccountNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS AccountNumber FROM #TempPR CROSS APPLY #TempPR.msgPayload.nodes('/ns0:PDFStmt') AS T1 ( C1 )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you want to count. What I know for sure is that you can count nodes in XML file in MSSQL versions like this:

```
declare @xml xml
select @xml= convert(xml,N'<ns0 xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123</empid><age>23</age></ns0>
<ns0 xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123</empid><age>32</age></ns0>    
<ns0 xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123</empid><age>23</age></ns0>
<ns0 xmlns:ns0="uri"><empid>123</empid><age>32</age></ns0>')

select count(*) as nr
from @xml.nodes('root/ns0/empid') as S(N)
```

Be aware that I modified also your xml because wasn't valid. i transformed
    empid>123 empid/> 
in
    empid>123 /empid>

, same for age

I removed :Statement and :PDF. This part is valid but i don't know the sysntax for searching throw nodes like this, but is working also for them.

Comment: I was not expecting just a count as given above. I need to find the number of accountno duplicates by filtering on xml column root node. As I clearly stated in my question, Each account number has two xmlpayload rows(one with 'statement' and 'pdf' as root) which is a valid record. If a account number has two rows with same root node those records are duplicates.